# How to Change Repository Information?

Tags: github

This might be a very stupid question but I am very new to github and do not know the right word to state the problem but may be this image might help :

[image]

As you can see for the first two of my repos there seems to be a repo details ( not sure about the term but I remember creating them when I created the repo url) but the last two doesnt have one .

I have been trying to find the option to set the repo details for the last two repos as they make it easier to know  about the the project without going inside each project for two hours now .Could somebody please tell me What are they called ?  How do you edit them for old repos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the smaller "Settings cog" in the top-right corner of your repo's main index page:

[image]

I agree it's hard to find and it *should* be in the main Repo Settings page. GitHub does solicit user feedback, so you should send that suggestion in.